# Animation for opening closing view in ListView, only one animation working

Tags: android, listview, animation, onclicklistener

I have a `ListView` that represents the 7 days of the week. Each `Row` has a header and content.

I have set the `Animations` for clicking the row header. When clicked, the content of that row will slide up/slide down.

Currently only the animation for slide down (opening the content) is working, and can't figure out why the slide up animation is not working ?!#&^@?!

**getView for adapter of ListView**

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_schedule, null);
        holder.header = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.header);
        holder.day = (CustomFontBoldTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.day);
        holder.isActive = (CustomFontBoldTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.is_active);
        holder.container = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.container);
        holder.rangeBar = (RangeBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rangebar);
        holder.tvStartTime = (CustomFontBoldTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.start_time);
        holder.tvEndTime = (CustomFontBoldTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.end_time);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.day.setText(schedules.get(position).getDay());

    if (schedules.get(position).getIsActive()) {
        holder.isActive.setText(R.string.btn_on);
        holder.isActive.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_green_rounded);
        holder.container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        holder.isActive.setText(R.string.btn_off);
        holder.isActive.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_gray_rounded);
        holder.container.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    holder.header.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (schedules.get(position).getIsActive()) {
                schedules.get(position).setIsActive(false);
                holder.container.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_up));
                holder.container.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.isActive.setText(R.string.btn_off);
                holder.isActive.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_gray_rounded);
            }
            else {
                schedules.get(position).setIsActive(true);
                holder.container.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_down));
                holder.container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.isActive.setText(R.string.btn_on);
                holder.isActive.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_green_rounded);
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

**Slide Down Animation**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

<scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:duration="250"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
```

**Slide Up Animation**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

<scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:duration="250"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0.0" />
```

Comment: Could it be that you set the view to View.GONE directly after calling the animation? It looks like your animation do not have any set time so I imagine it hits the next line of code quite quickly.

Comment: @RedRumming unfortunately this did not fix it. Thanks for the input!